# Preloadjs isn't loading images/bitmaps correctly

Tags: bitmapimage, easeljs, createjs, preloading

I'm trying to preload the images and then put them into bitmaps. This is on a server and the src is correct. Not sure what's going on exactly? I'm new to preloadjs.  I can't seem to retrieve the image to use it. They're from the same exact source yet one works and the other doesn't, and I can write to the canvas and it works just fine?

```
function handleComplete(){
    var ret = new createjs.Text("hi!", "24px sans-serif");
        ret.x = 5;
        ret.y = 5;
        stage.addChild(ret);

    var image = preload.getResult("imgC");
    var pic =  new createjs.Bitmap(image); //this doesn't?
    stage.addChild(pic);
    stage.update();

    $('img').attr("src", "extra/DNA/c.png");//this works
    $('img').attr("src", image); //doesn't work
}

preload.on("complete", handleComplete(), this);
preload.loadFile({id:"imgC", src:"extra/DNA/c.png"});
```

I noticed I am getting a few errors from Chrome:

failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'handleEvent' of undefined

and firefox:

typeError: b is undefined (reference to preloadjs line 12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible the content can't be loaded by XHR (xmlhttprequests), which preloadJS uses by default for images. Try initializing the queue with `useXHR=false`. If you load the image using the path in an EaselJS bitmap, it just does an image tag request, which isn't affected by cross-domain issues.

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
// other load code here
```

Comment: This option helped with the problem, thank you. Do you happen to know why the content can not be loaded by XHR? In my case those are just normal png/jpg files stored in the same server, and works fine on most browsers, but cannot be loaded by some Android devices' browsers.

Comment: Interesting, I don't know why that would be. Could be that the browser treats it as a local file or something.